# implementation of custom ImageSwitcher in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build news application I want to make the news shows as picture and title in image switcher like BBC application

[image]

I was trying to use:

```
public View makeView() {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = vi.inflate(R.layout.image_switcher_content, null);
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_switcher_image);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_image_switcher);
        return view;
    }
```

But I can't figure out how to use every `imageview` and `textview` in every child while I'm receiving the images and texts from web service please help .

Comment: your question is too broad and you haven't displayed enough code to support it. please refine your question to a specific task. Instead of "i'm building a news application" try "I'm building an image switcher however when I try this, this problem occurs" giving specific code, debugger reports, etc

Comment: there is no error i wont the idea of how implement custom ImageSwitcher instead of just image i want to put image ind text view

Comment: Now that you've added a picture I understand your question more, and it seems as though you haven't done enough research. You have to learn basic android tutorials first and then what you are asking is quite simple. Create an XML layout template for each box (one image + text view), and then create another XML layout for the main view and reference your template as many times as you need dynamically. It's still a very broad question so you have to go back and do more research and attempt something yourself.

Comment: the content in the picture are listView in every child in it textview contain title and imageswitcher contain image and title of the news if you can implement custom imageswitcher